# Crypt in perl, decrypt in delphi7

Tags: perl, delphi, encryption, compatibility

I need not so strong crypt method in Perl, which will be compatible decryption in Delphi7.

To crypt some string value in Perl which http get from Delphi7.

I prefer simple solution based on standard libraries/modules, if it possible.

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure what you're looking for. Say I have a string, and a password of *swordfish*, and I used that to encrypt the string. You would want to be able to decrypt the string with the same password. Is that correct?

The standard Perl `crypt` command is a ***hash*** -- a *one way* encryption system. That is, it generates a hash that you can use to encrypt a string, but won't be able to decrypt that string even if you know the password. It's mainly used to store the hash instead of a password. That way, if someone types in a new password, you can encrypt that and verify it against the hash.

What you want is a full blown encryption/decryption algorithm. Something like [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29), a tough cypher that's open source, so widely implemented. That way, you're likely to find a encryption/decription module in both Delphi and Perl that'll match. Fortunately, Perl has a module called [Crypt::Blowfish](http://search.cpan.org/~dparis/Crypt-Blowfish-2.12/Blowfish.pm) that will allow you to encrypt and decrypt using Blowfish. I saw an [open source](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt) page of various encrypt/decrypt modules including one that does Blowfish.

If that doesn't work, you can try [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard). Again the open source Delphi encryption library and Perl have modules that can do DES encryption/decryption. Perl's module is [Crypt::DES](http://search.cpan.org/~dparis/Crypt-DES-2.05/DES.pm).